# How to access struct members from pointer

Tags: c

I'm having trouble accessing a struct's members when passed a void* pointer to that structure's base address. Can anyone offer a solution or explain the error to me? Right now I get the message "goroutines.c:142:31: error: request for member ‘qtail’ in something not a structure or union"

```
    //Channel struct
struct channel{
    int magicnumber;
    int length;
    int capacity;

    struct gcb* qhead; //head of the queue
    struct gcb* qtail; //tail of the queue
};


void *makeChannel(int dataLength, int capacity){
  if( dataLength <= 0){
    panic( "data length must be greater than zero" );
  }
  if( capacity < 0){
    panic( "capacity must be non-negative" );
  }
  struct channel* ch = (struct channel* )malloc( dataLength * capacity );
  ch->magicnumber = 0x1ca91ac3;
  ch->capacity = capacity;
  ch->length = 0;
  return ch;
}

void sendChannel(void *channel, void *fetchAddress){
  if( capChannel( channel ) == lenChannel( channel ) ){

    (struct channel* )&channel->qtail->next = head;
  }
}
```

Comment: the correct fix is to use `struct channel *channel` since that's what it is. If you really *insist* it should be this `void *`, then you should know the precedence of casts: `((struct channel *)channel)->`. Easier to *assign* to a temporary of type `struct channel *` anyway though.

Comment: OT: `makeChannel()` misses to initialise `qhead` and `qtail`. You probably want to set them to `NULL`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not valid to de-reference a `void*` pointer.  The de-referencing is basically a numerical off-set from the base-pointer.  If the compiler does not know what type the pointer is, how can it know the offset amount, nor is it able to decide whether the member reference is actually valid.

In your function it is cast,   It looks like there's a stray `&`.

```
void sendChannel(void *channel, void *fetchAddress)
{
    struct channel *chan = (struct channel *)channel;

    if( capChannel( chan ) == lenChannel( chan ) )
    {
        chan->qtail->next = head;
    }
}
```

But your cast is not applied to anything.  I prefer to make the cast explicit, by assigning it to a temporary local variable.  I feel this makes the resultant code more readable, as it's not full of type-casts here & there.

Answer (score 3):

The operator `->` has lower precedence and so is evaluated first. `channel` is a void pointer so, when `channel->` de-references it, you obtain a value of type `void` instead of the expected `struct channel`.

Add parenthesis around the cast and `channel` (or pass `channel` around as a `struct channel *` rather than `void*` to avoid repeated casting):

```cpp
((struct channel *)channel)->qtail->next = head;
```